# Getting the data inside the <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have an A tag which navigates to to a #page1 on clicking . Inside the tag, i have a variable named question

My question is, how can i get the value of the variable question in page1.??

Thanks

Comment: can you give a sample mark up of your `<a>`?

Comment: Variables do not exist in a markup language. Do you mean in JavaScript?

Comment: <a href="#page1"><div id="n"></div></a> . I will load the data for the div tag from javascript's document.ready() dunction. On clicking the link , i need the data of the div tag to be accessed from page1. I dont know if i have to use javascript in ready function to paste the data in another <div> tag in page1 or do something else. I doubt if the div tag in page1 will be accessible from ready function

Comment: Let me clarify a couple of things  -you are clicking on local anchor tags (ie not navigating to another page)? -what data do you need from the div (its id? contents between div tags?)?

Comment: it moves to another page within the same html document . in jquery,u can have several pages within same html document right ? i need the data between div tags.

Comment: A "page" is usually a new HTML document object.  You can't have more than one document object, no matter what framework.  Your question is not very clear, I'd suggest taking ten minutes to set up a http://jsfiddle.net/ to show us what you mean.

Comment: @Steve Hi, I have added the required portion of my code in jsfiddle. It wont work , but you will get an idea of what i mean. Please access it from here http://jsfiddle.net/BzFwq/

Comment: @Hari, That is still just one page. As Steve mentioned, you can only have one HTML document per page. What you have is a local anchor tag that is pointing to data on the same page. You are still on the same page and have not moved to another page. And Michal's answer below should do what you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And just for laughs - in pure javascript:

```
<script>
anchors=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
 for(i=0;i<anchors.length;i++)
 {
    link = anchors[i].href
    arr = link.split("#");
  value = (arr[1]=="page1")?anchors[i].innerHTML:'';
  }
</script>
```

if you need the contents of the div without the html (using jquery)

```
var value = $('a[href="#page1"]>div').text()
```

Comment: what do you mean by just for laughs ?

Comment: If you are using jquery  you are better off using its selectors. The pure javascript version works well but as you can see you need to write several lines of code to get the same result as with the jquery solution. If you don't want jquery - this is the way to go. The just for laughs part refers to how awkward it used to be before jquery.

Answer (score 2):

```
var value = $('a[href="#page1"]').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant of Michael's pure JS:

```
<script type='text/javascript>
anchors=document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(x=0;x<anchors.length;x++) {
  alert(anchors[x].childNodes[0].id);
}
</script>
```

Comment: anchors[x].childNodes[0].id will give me the id of the tag. I need the data of that tag. I guess its got to be innerHTML. But, its not that helpful for my application. Please read my comment under the question